# git: How do I reconfigure git to use bright red and bright green?

Tags: git, git-bash

Git uses colors that, under certain weather conditions, are too dim to be readable on black background.

How do I reconfigure git to use bright colors? (In particular, bright red and bright green in `git diff`)

I need this for both Windows and Linux.

I found "C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig", but there is nothing about colors.

UPD

For `color.status.<slot>`, adding

```
[color.status]
        untracked = yellow
```

works, but is not what I want;

```
[color.status]
        untracked = brightred
```

is the same as `normal` or `white`

```
>git --version
git version 2.26.2.windows.1
```

UPD2

For Ubuntu Linux, by default .gitconfig does not exist, but if I create it with the above lines inside, I get an error:

```
$ git status 
error: invalid color value: brightred
fatal: bad config variable 'color.status.untracked' in file '/home/me/.gitconfig' at line 2
```

(It works with `yellow`, but not `brightred`)

```
$ git --version
git version 2.25.1
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Comment: Relevant part of the docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colordiffltslotgt

Comment: What terminal are you using and what does `echo $TERM` produce in your terminal?  These values should work, but they depend on your terminal being reasonably capable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like bright colors are a new feature; now it is 2020, by the time that you read this, the problem may be already fixed.

A workaround for Windows: taking into account that unknown colors (e.g. brightwhite) are interpreted as white, I configured my git to use white on red/green:

```
[color.status]
    untracked = brightwhite red
    changed = brightwhite red

[color.diff]
    oldMoved = brightwhite red
    newMoved = brightgreen green

    old = brightwhite red
    new = brightwhite green
```